# Cookie and session in towerjs

Tags: node.js, connect, towerjs

is there some simple example how to use cookies or sessions in towerjs? 
I read about Connect Middleware, but I have no experience with it (and unfortunately with node.js also).

If examples are not available I will be grateful for any tips too.

Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cookies**

From the TowerJS source code [here](https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/master/src/tower/controller/instrumentation.coffee#L57-62), the controller has these properties:

- `@request`
- `@response`
- `@cookies` (which is just a shortcut for `@request.cookies`)
- `@session` (which is just a shortcut for `@request.session`)

Hence to set cookies you can follow express documentation [here](http://expressjs.com/guide.html)

For example this set cookie 'rememberme'

```
# "Remember me" for 15 minutes 
@response.cookie 'rememberme', 'yes', 
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000)
  httpOnly: true
```

And to get the cookie

```
@request.cookies.rememberme
```

**Session**

As for session, looks like it's just connect in memory session. See source code here
https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/master/src/tower/server/application.coffee#L39

So you can just use it like:

```
@request.session.something = 'something'
```

or

```
@session.something = 'something'
```

Ok hope that helps...

Comment: Yes, this what I needed.
Just one thing. When I create session variable like in your example @session.something = 'something', I should have access to this variable in all subsites. But I do not have. In other subsite I get "undefined" output.

Anyway thank you very much. Cookies works well :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you meant by 'subsite', but basically since it's default session store used by Tower is 'in-memory', so it's associated to a single node.js process. If you have multiple node.js processes, then you need to store the session externally, for example something like https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis

Answer (score 0):

In the Tower.js github repo they are using sessions in the example [here](https://github.com/viatropos/tower/tree/master/test/example). Maybe you can get some help there. I'm not the coffee script guy, so my help is limited. ;)

But this is where they configure session/cookie support:

```
// config/application.coffee
@use "cookieParser", Tower.config.session.key
@use "session", secret: Tower.config.session.secret, cookie: {domain: Tower.config.session.cookie.domain}
```

I hope I could help at least a little! ;)

Comment: thank you for your interest. Yes I am trying to use this configuration and I am trying right now implement a 'view counter' example from http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html
Unfortunately with no results. Well I am going to digging further.

Greets! :)